# CSS is it possible to make a scrolling element not show in top part of the window

Tags: css

It is difficult to explain, a picture (two in this case) is worth a 1000 words.

I have

- a full image background,
- a fixed header with a navigation bar represented here below in solid orange,
- some scrollable content represented here below in transparent yellow.

I would like that the scrollable element  doesn't show above the orange strip, so that it doesn't show in the top 100px of the screen. Can this achieved?

The image in the background, which is an image not the background of the body, has the following style:

```
#full-screen-background-image {
  z-index: -999;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

[image: the elements]
[image: undesired effect]

Comment: Do you want the content to be hidden or to stop scrolling? What about just applying a `margin-top` to the yellow content area?

Comment: What about duplicating the part of the background that is above the orange header as a separate image, and z-indexing it above the yellow content.  That way, when the yellow content scrolls up, it is covered by the image.  Does that match what you're asking for?

Comment: @TimGoodman I thought about that, but the background image resizes with window width, the image is min-height: 100%; min-width: 1024px; width: 100%;

Comment: You could still do what Tim suggests by having 2 *layers* containing similar image content, but the one on top is clipped using the `clip` property.

Comment: @cimmanon, thank you for the suggestion. Yes, I was looking for something like a mask, I wasn't aware of the clip property. This said, I couldn't find a way of having it work with resizing background images. I guess I will change my design.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdanek/TNRkY/1/ check out this fiddle

HTML structure is pretty basic, I've just added a wrapper to the content. It has `position :fixed` and `overflow: auto` so it allows the contents to scroll.

```
.bg { 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: -1; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    background: #cfc; 
}
.toolbar { 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 100; 
    top: 100px; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    height: 50px; 
    background: #fcc; 
}
.wrap { 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 50; 
    overflow: auto; 
    top: 150px; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0; 
}
.content { 
    background: #ffc; 
    margin-top: 50px; 
}
```

Comment: One thing - if you want the scrollbar to show for the whole window height just set `.wrap` top value to 0 and add `margin-top: 200px` to `.content`.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but as the scroll bar doesn't go to the top of the window it messes the alignments of the pages elements. I guess I will have to change my design idea.